# Export data Wrapper API on top of Existing API

Tags: c#, .net, wrapper

```
[ HttpPost ]
    public async Task< IHttpActionResult > Calculate(MeasureCalculationRequest measureCalculationRequest )
```

- I have a REST API which will give me list of records based on the pagination I - pass in request.
- I am trying to create a Export to CSV API wrapper on top of Exisitng API. How can I do that?
- Also i would like to know if there are any design patterns I should follow.